# How to get an array item having a property value which is maximum amongst array items

Tags: javascript

I have an array of items `matchingItemsCurrentRow`. It has items of type `IBwFormSectionItem` which has a property `runCount`. I want to get an array item which has the maximum `runCount` value. How can I get it?

The type definition of `IBwFormSectionItem` is given below:

```
export interface IBwFormSectionItem {
    meta?: IBwFormItemMetadata[],
    font?: IBwFormFont,
    col?: number,
    row?: number,
    colSpan?: number,
    rowSpan?: number,
    text?: string,
    runs?: boolean,
    runCount?: number,
    height?: number,
    width?: number
}
```

Comment: Please post the data that you have in JSON format, as well as the expected output.

Comment: This question has been asked and answered many times. Most solutions use `reduce` to loop across the items.

Comment: didnt get wat your trying to do .if you want to get the max value from the array try this code ...Math.max.apply(this,[1,2,3,4]);

Comment: I do not only want the max value but the whole object that has that max value.

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way referring torazaburo's comment.

```
maxRunCountItem = matchingItemsCurrentRow.reduce((item1, item2) => {                        
    return item1.runCount > item2.runCount ? item1 : item2;
});
```